# Consume the Json in kafka topic using tJava in Talend

Tags: java, json, talend

I am currently trying to create an ingestion job workflow using kafka in Talend Studio. The job will read the json data in topic "work" and store into the hive table.

Snippet of json:

```
{"Header": {"Vers":"1.0","Message": "318","Owner": {"ID": 102,"FID": 101},"Mode":"8"},"Request": {"Type":"4","ObjType": "S","OrderParam":[{"Code": "OpType","Value": "30"},{"Code": "Time","Value": "202"},{"Code": "AddProperty","ObjParam": [{"Param": [{"Code": "Sync","Value": "Y"}]}]}]}}
{"Header": {"Vers":"2.0","Message": "318","Owner": {"ID": 103,"FID": 102},"Mode":"8"},"Request": {"Type":"5","ObjType": "S","OrderParam":[{"Code": "OpType","Value": "90"},{"Code": "Time","Value": "203"},{"Code": "AddProperty","ObjParam": [{"Param": [{"Code": "Sync","Value": "Y"}]}]}]}}
```

Talend workflow:

[image]

My focus in this question is not the talend component. But the java code in tJava component that uses the java to fetch and read the json.

Java code:

```
String output=((String)globalMap.get("tLogRow_1_OUTPUT"));

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(output);
System.out.println(jsonObject);

String sourceDBName=(jsonObject.getString("Vers"));
```

The code above able to get the data from tLogRow in "output" variable. However, it gives an error where it read null value for json object. What should I do to correctly get the data from json accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `tExtractJsonFields` instead of a tJava. This component extracts data from your input String following a json schema that you can define in metadata. With this you could extract all fields from your input .